# How to minimize memory allocation on embedded platforms?

Tags: c++, arduino

How do you minimize dynamic memory allocation in C++?

I'm writing some sketches for an Arduino Mega, and on occasion it's hanging, and I suspect it's suffering from memory fragmentation. However, I'm a little unclear as to when variables are allocated.

If I have a class with a method `do_stuff` like:

```
class MyController{

public:
    MyController(){
        ...init...
    }

    void do_stuff(){
        int value = 123;
    }
};
```

I instantiate `MyController` once but then execute `do_stuff()` multiple times. Does the program dynamically allocate `value` each time I call the method or just once when I instantiate the class?

If the former, would it be better to change the method variable to a class variable, so it's only allocated once, and doesn't risk fragmenting the heap?

Comment: do you change value at all?  why do you talk about heap fragmentation when the variable you're asking about is on the stack?

Comment: I would imagine it's allocated on the call stack, not the heap, but my C++ is fairly limited. And depending on the compliation and context it may even be optimized out

Comment: int value is allocated on the stack and not heap

Comment: There is no dynamic allocation going on in your example.  `value` has automatic storage duration.

Comment: Usual suspect is Arduino String class and using its concatenations like  `someString += anotherString + "blabla" + ..........`. It's usually used to spare some Serial.print() calls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On typical platforms, and I don't believe an Arduino is different in this respect, `int value` probably won't take memory. It will be in a register. (Small variable, local). If not, it will be on the CPU stack, which doesn't fragment, and it recycled whenever the function returns.

Answer (score 0):

I can't say where `MyController` will be instantiated, but each call of `do_stuff` instantiates `value` on the **stack once**. This memory will be freed as soon as `do_stuff` is left and since there is no recursion, there will not be several instances of `value` at once.